# firebase.notifications().getInitialNotification() doesn't work when app is in background in IOS

Tags: react-native

I am getting notifications but when the app is in background below code doesn't work in IOS. I want to redirect the user to a specific page when a user comes to the app through notification.
i follow below procedure[enter link description here](https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v4.3.x/notifications/receiving-notifications?source=post_page-----349fff071591----------------------)

```
componentDidMount()
{
const notificationOpen: NotificationOpen = await firebase
     .notifications()
     .getInitialNotification();
   if (notificationOpen) {
    alert("getInitialNossssssssstification");

     if (this.state.isUser) {
       await AsyncStorage.setItem("getNotificationsKey", "true");
       // console.log("jkasghfghdfgj isUser true");
     } else {
       // console.log("jkasghfghdfgj isUser false");
     }
   } else {
     console.log("elseeeeeeee");
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add code for notifications open as below :

```js
componentDidMount() {
    this.notificationOpenedListener = firebase.notifications().onNotificationOpened((notification) => {
        alert("getInitialNossssssssstification");

        if (this.state.isUser) {
            await AsyncStorage.setItem("getNotificationsKey", "true");
            // console.log("jkasghfghdfgj isUser true");
        } else {
            // console.log("jkasghfghdfgj isUser false");
        }
    });
}

componentWillUnmount() {
    this.notificationOpenedListener();
}
```